# Cant route urls with Flask-babel and blueprints when url doesnt specify language

Tags: python, flask, flask-babel

I have been digging around Flask-babel for a while and cant seem to get the `url routing` with a simple `blueprint`. Here's the trimmed down app

on my **__ init __.py file**,

```
app = Flask(__name__)
babel.init_app(app)


@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    return g.get('lang_code', 'fr')


from .mod_main import mod_main as main_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint,url_prefix='/<lang_code>')
```

In the **blueprint views.py** file

```
@mod_main.url_defaults
def add_language_code(endpoint, values):
    values.setdefault('lang_code', g.lang_code)


@mod_main.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code')


@mod_main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('main/index.html')
```

This works perfectly fine as long as i navigate to `http://localhost:5000/fr` but when I navigate to `http://localhost:5000/` (without the lang),i get the 404 error. Normal - since  the blueprint is expecting a lang_code as a prefix.

On first time when a user navigates to `http://localhost:5000/` (without lang), I expect the site to show pages with the language in 'fr'. If the user then switches it to English, and navigates to `http://localhost:5000/`, i would like it to show up in english but not in french. Cant seem to get this working !!!

Comment: You don't have a route registered for `'/'`. All of the blueprint's routes begin with `'/<lang_code>'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution - all I needed to do was add a `before_request` function on the app to check for request.view_args and serve the right language based on the session variable.

I also figured out the `g` variable in flask is valid only for the active request and cannot be used to store values across requests. (As i was trying to store the lang on the g variable across requests - had to use the session variable to transfer values across requests)

I just uploaded a stripped down app implementing babel with blueprints here : https://github.com/shankararul/simple-babel

Comment: Hello, can you tell me how to deal with 2 language with blueprint but without babel  ?